# How can i resolve this issue of database in crystal report?

Tags: database, crystal-reports, odbc, plsqldeveloper, sage50

I have a report up and running in sage 50 with crystal report.

I have another server up and running with sage 50 but with a diferent filename, same version of sage 50 and crystal report.

When i try to run the report its giving me a error . (logically because is a different filename or database)

This error comes

[image: [error]

I need to run the report on the second system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the report's connection or the existing local ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

Select Database > Set Datasource Location and update it accordingly.

The report is currently pointing to a database source you either have no access to or does not exist, you need to change it to a source you can access.